# Splitting header image (tower) to navbar and content via CSS / HTML (with Demo)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to have a "bigger" header image for my website.
So I cutted the top from the bottom and putting the top to the navbar and the bottom in the content as header image.

This looks like you can see here.
https://fiddle.jshell.net/09p6v2mu/

Maybe you can improve this demo example so that it is better.
- Not the image. The CSS.

Its working - but not **perfect** I think.

Or? What's your feedback?
Positioning with absolute is ok?

I thought there was another way to make this much better.
But maybe this is the best way :) Don't know.

Thanks in Advance!

[image: Example picture]

Comment: Please provide a more meaningful explanation of what you want to obtain. What do you mean by bigger? Do you want mobile support?

Comment: Maybe there is a more responsive method to do this. I dont like this big absolute positioning.